# How To Capture Flash in Module Window?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Is there a way to capture video playing in a flash player module? From what I see there is no cache or at least the player settings are set to no cache and no store.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replay Media Catcher is a good program, http://applian.com/download-videos/ to capture flash streams

This is a list of more programs which are similar

http://stream-recorder.com/forum/record-rtmp-flash-video-flv-stream-embedded-t2324.html